# Google Cloud Dataflow Python --maxNumWorkers

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to increase the number of workers for a dataflow pipeline built with the Apache Beam's python SDK and I found documentation that suggested setting `--maxNumWorkers=` flag would be sufficient to increase the maximum number of workers beyond the default value of 15.  However, when I add this flag to the pipeline options, it does not seem to work.  I looked back at the execution parameter options documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/specifying-exec-params) and noticed that the `maxNumWorkers` was not listed in the Python "Specifying Other Cloud Pipeline Options" while it does appear in the Java SDK -- is this a known limitation of the Python package? Are there any other options I am not considering to set the maxNumWorkers within the python pipeline options?

Note: I have confirmed that this is not a quota issue as I can specify `--num_workers=100` but this (I believe) will not use the autoscaling algorithm as it immediately set the number of workers to 100.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like in Python the option is [--max_num_workers](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/a3a7807fec68a7954ba136dc00499649d372f5ca/sdks/python/apache_beam/options/pipeline_options.py#L417).